# Replying to professor after months

Tags: research-undergraduate, projects

I'm a sophomore undergrad and had approached a professor from my department towards the end of my freshman year to work under a project under him in the summer. However, the projects he supervised required learning (I didn't have the necessary background for research projects) and hence rather than just a summer project it was going to be a longer project. Due to COVID, I did some tasks and communicated twice within 2 weeks but ended up replying to him after 3 months during the next time because (external factors, I said in a mail to him) I was just very confused about the work. He still replied and confirmed if I was interested in the work but around the same time my college resumed virtually and I got slumped with a lot of work. I'm still confused about the task and I didn't get to work on it at all. It's been again 2 months and my university's schedule keeps me so busy that I feel it'll be bad if I reply with no work. I get a lot of smaller slots to work rather than a larger slot. The latter helps me focus if I'm learning something new or thinking originally, the former do not. I really feel like it's a disrespect to him even though I didn't mean to. I really want to do the work. Is there anything I can do to salvage this situation?

Usually, at my university, newly sophomore students do not get to work on research projects under professors due to lack of necessary background. I had the opportunity to learn too, I feel like I wasted an opportunity on hand.

Comment: I was supposed to do this project with a partner, she's been really busy too.

Comment: Well, what do you have to lose when you very politely apologize and ask if he is happy to take up the line again, despite your long absence. Worst case, they won't answer.

Comment: Related https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/151426/68109

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I did that once, and I feel like this might be disrespectful for him if I do that again. I'm not sure :(

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thank you but I don't think anyone ghosts their professor for months :((

Comment: Once is ok. Twice is so-so. Thrice is nagging.